# Matlab, legends in a barplot

Tags: matlab

I'm having a for loop which creates a barchart with 4 bars on the basis on 2 vectors.
two bars are red and two are green. Red and green means two different things. I would like to show that in a legend, but how am I going to do it. I've tried several things but nothings seems to do what i want. My latest output gave a legend like this:`

```
'red color' Wrong answer
'red color' Wrong answer
'green color' right answer'
'green color' right answer
```

as you can see the output gave me 4 legends but I just want 2.
How can fix this:

```
R = [-1 -1 1 1];
T = [2.0741 2.1521 2.9529 2];
figure;  
% Barchart
for i=1:length(T)
   h = bar(i, T(i));
     if i == 1 hold on, end
     if R(i) == -1
       col = 'r';
       legendInfo{i} = ['Wrong answer '];
     else
       col = 'g';
       legendInfo{i} = ['Right answer '];
     end

     set(h, 'FaceColor', col)

end

set(gca,'xTick',1:length(R),'xTickLabel',1:length(R))
xlabel('question number.');
ylabel('time per question')
legend(legendInfo)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass handles to `legend` to specify which entries you want to have:

```
R = [-1 -1 1 1];
T = [2.0741 2.1521 2.9529 2];
figure;  
% Barchart
for i=1:length(T)
   h(i) = bar(i, T(i));
     if i == 1 hold on, end
     if R(i) == -1
       col = 'r';
       legendInfo{i} = ['Wrong answer '];
     else
       col = 'g';
       legendInfo{i} = ['Right answer '];
     end

     set(h(i), 'FaceColor', col)

end
set(gca,'xTick',1:length(R),'xTickLabel',1:length(R))
xlabel('question number.');
ylabel('time per question')

[~,legendsIWant]=unique(R)
legend(h(legendsIWant),legendInfo(legendsIWant));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, It works just great. I did not know it could be solved in that way..

Comment: I was wondering if you had a link to a place where I can read more about this legendIWant ?

Comment: legendsIWant is a simple variable, it contains `[1,3]`, which means that the first and third box should show up in the legend. Instead of hard-coding this numbers, I used the already existing variable R to determine it. `h(legendsIWant)` simply selects the first and third handle to the graphics object, and `legendInfo(legendsIWant)` selects the first and third text.